# Exception happening randomly on WebSphere 9

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-traditional

We've an application deployed on WAS 9 (JSF, in case it matters) and noticed that, randomly, the application stops working properly after a redeployment (all POST requests fail and we're always redirected to the homepage).

The log shows the same error happening everytime we click a button in the application, that, in a nutshell, is an Oracle error complaining about an insertion using a duplicate key (every action performed on the application is audited and that's the insertion that is failing and causing the error).
After some digging, I also noticed that the problem was occurring only on some browsers and that deleting the cookies and restaring the browser "solved" the problem.

The same application is running without any issue on GlassFish, so this is cleary a problem with WebSphere.

My layman's conclusion is that the server is caching something it shouldn't and running the same insert over and over again, hence the exception.

Is this a known issue? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

This is probably related to other problem I reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379776/websphere-9-restart-application), but I'm just guessing.

Here's the relevant part of the log:

```
Error Code: 1
Call: INSERT INTO AUDIT (EVENT_ACTION_TYPE, EVENT_DESCRIPTION, EVENT_LOGICAL_NAME, EVENT_ORIGIN, EVENT_RESULT, EVENT_USERNAME, EVENT_TIMESTAMP, EVENT_MODULE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                bind => [LOGOUT, john.doe, N/A, localhost, S, system, 2016-12-21 16:35:19.821, ECC]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(x.EccAudit[ eccAuditPK=x.EccAuditPK[ eventUsername=system, eventTimestamp=Wed Dec 21 16:35:19 WET 2016, eventModule=ECC ] ])
                at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:902) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:964) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:633) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2061) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:309) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:911) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:810) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2899) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1863) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1845) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1796) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:227) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:126) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4275) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1444) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1534) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:278) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commit(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1116) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:137) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.DuplicateKeyException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (EPMS_CL1.ECC_AUDIT_PK) violated

                at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor150.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437) ~[na:2.6 (04-27-2016)]
                at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapExceptionHelper(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:628) ~[rsahelpers.jar:WAS90.SERV1 [cf011635.01]]
                at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapException(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:687) ~[rsahelpers.jar:WAS90.SERV1 [cf011635.01]]
                at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.mapException(AdapterUtil.java:2273) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.mapException(WSJdbcUtil.java:1191) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:822) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:892) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                ... 76 common frames omitted
[12/21/16 16:35:19:837 WET] 0000018f SystemOut     O [ERROR] -
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:178) ~[com.ibm.ws.jpa.eclipselink.jar:na]
                at pt.sibs.epms.persistence.facade.AbstractFacade.execute(AbstractFacade.java:102) [epms-persistence.jar:EPMS V11120002L]
                at pt.sibs.epms.persistence.facade.AbstractFacade.create(AbstractFacade.java:51) [epms-persistence.jar:EPMS V11120002L]
                at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.audit.AuditController.audit(AuditController.java:139) [classes/:na]
                at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.audit.AuditController.audit(AuditController.java:74) [classes/:na]
                at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.audit.AuditController.auditSuccess(AuditController.java:173) [classes/:na]
                at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.listener.SessionAttributeListener.attributeRemoved(SessionAttributeListener.java:58) [classes/:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionAttributeObserver.sessionAttributeRemoved(HttpSessionAttributeObserver.java:157) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionStateEventDispatcher.sessionAttributeRemoved(SessionStateEventDispatcher.java:137) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.StoreCallback.sessionAttributeRemoved(StoreCallback.java:191) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession.removeAttribute(MemorySession.java:496) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession.invalidate(MemorySession.java:243) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionImpl.invalidate(HttpSessionImpl.java:303) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.invalidate(SessionData.java:247) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.security.LiveSessionsObserver.addLiveSession(LiveSessionsObserver.java:39) [classes/:na]
                at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.listener.SessionAttributeListener.attributeAdded(SessionAttributeListener.java:47) [classes/:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionAttributeObserver.sessionAttributeSet(HttpSessionAttributeObserver.java:132) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionStateEventDispatcher.sessionAttributeSet(SessionStateEventDispatcher.java:110) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.StoreCallback.sessionAttributeSet(StoreCallback.java:178) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.store.memory.MemorySession.setAttribute(MemorySession.java:474) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.http.HttpSessionImpl.setAttribute(HttpSessionImpl.java:251) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.putSessionValue(SessionData.java:293) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.setAttribute(SessionData.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.session.HttpSessionFacade.setAttribute(HttpSessionFacade.java:169) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doBeforeProcessing(AuthenticationFilter.java:52) [classes/:na]
                at pt.sibs.epms.ecc.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:82) [classes/:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:961) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
```

**EDIT #1**

The log also starts showing the following warning message:

```
000000f2 WASSessionCor W SessionAffinityManager setNextId Detected JSESSIONID with invalid length; expected length of 23, found 24, setting: 6a559228ee4bcdc3c90f58ac to null.
```

**EDIT #2**

I've also noticed that my logout method is not working correctly because the call `if( request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() )` is always returning `false`, but it shouldn't.

Comment: Since the other question involved your application ThreadPoolManager.init() and a singleton.. and since there's no tran active on the thread in this one....  I'd wonder what you're doing in your ThreadPoolManager?   Possibly a useful starting point if you don't hear any better ideas.

Comment: You should be able to debug this form you development machine. There are two exception PK violation, and missing transaction. What is the order? Is this an insert performed by your code, or the container. Why is there no problem during the first deployment. You should be able to answer this, by some good old debugging, and reading some source code.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Scott, the application has several threads (~8) waiting for requests via Socket. The ThreadPoolManager is used so that the threads are managed by the container, with a Managed Thread Factory.
Klaus, the inserts are performed by my code. The application has an action listener that performs the insertion everytime it's invoked. 
Remember that the application works without problems both on GlassFish and WildFly, the problem is just happening on WebSphere 9.

Comment: @Klaus, the order of the exceptions is the following:

- `DuplicateKeyException` on the insert due to PK violation;

- `IllegalStateException` on the rollback because no transaction is currently active (this can, eventually, be an application's bug, which I will investigate, but is not the root problem);

Comment: `JSESSIONID with invalid length; expected length ` message is printed when request with incorrect session cookie is sent to the server. It is usually caused by having other vendor server on the same box (like Tomcat, Glassfish etc), which uses same cookie name but different length. I'd suggest to change cookie name for one of these servers or for WebSphere in the server configuration.

Comment: @Gas, you're probably right about that, as I've mentioned, I'm using different application servers and am setting the cookie's name inside web.xml. Thanks.